# Can't rake db:migrate due to sqlite3_busy timeout

Tags: sqlite, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I'm running RVM with Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.0rc. When I run `rake db:migrate`, I get:

```
Expected argument 0 of type sqlite3 *, but got SWIG::TYPE_p_sqlite3 #<SWIG::TYPE_p_sqlite3:0x00000... 
      in SWIG method 'sqlite3_busy_timeout'
```

Has anyone run into this?

And more importantly, has anyone fixed it and how?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a more Stable version of Rails 3? What version of the sqllite3 Gem are you using?